# How to Dynamically Determine Bindings in Google Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am currently implementing a certain functionality with Factory classes as follows:

```
public class TemplateFactory {

    Template template = null;

    public static Template createTemplate(Message message){
        if(Message.getMessageId() == Message.WELCOME_MESSAGE) {
            template = new WelcomeTemplate(message);
        } else if (Message.getMessageId == Message.RESET_PASSWORD){
            template = new ResetPasswordTemplate(message);
        }
        return template;
    }
}

public class TemplateClient {
    public static void Main(String[] args){
        Message message = new Message(args[0]);
        Template template = TemplateFactory.createTemplate(message);
        template.doSomething();
    }
}
```

How do you implement this with Google Guice considering that bindings are determined dynamically during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the guice extension called [AssistedInject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) for creating factories.

Comment: I have had a look at it and since an new to Guice I find it confusing. Please assist with a quick example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MapBinder is what you are looking for: http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html